# How do I move the cursor to the *Warnings* buffer whenever there is a new warning?

Tags: hooks, warning

I want to focus the `*Warnings*` buffer whenever there is new warning. I tried this:

```lisp
(add-hook 'special-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when (string= (buffer-name (current-buffer))
                           "*Warnings*")
              (pop-to-buffer (current-buffer)))))
```

However, the cursor only moves to the `*Warnings*` buffer on the first warning. Subsequent warnings do not move to the cursor to the `*Warnings*` buffer. What do I need to do to move the cursor to the `*Warnings*` buffer whenever there is a new warning?

Emacs version: GNU Emacs 26.3.

Answer (score 2):

I am a strong believer in not polluting hooks, especially something so fundamental like `special-mode` that is used by countless other major-modes.  As such, I would recommend *not* using the `special-mode-hook`.  The following example adds an entry to the `display-buffer-alist` that will trigger a custom `display-buffer-...` function when a matching regexp exists.

[The internal function `window--display-buffer` has five (5) arguments in Emacs 25 and Emacs 26, but only four (4) arguments in Emacs 27.  This example should work on all of the aforementioned versions of Emacs.]

```lisp
(defun display-buffer-fn (buffer-or-name alist direction &optional size pixelwise)
  "BUFFER:  The buffer that will be displayed.
  ALIST:  See the doc-string of `display-buffer' for more information.
  DIRECTION:  Must use one of these symbols:  'left 'right 'below 'above
  SIZE:  See the doc-string for `split-window'.
  PIXELWISE:  See the doc-string for `split-window'.
  There are three possibilities:
  -  (1) If a window on the frame already displays the target buffer,
  then just reuse the same window.
  -  (2) If there is already a window in the specified direction in relation
  to the selected window, then display the target buffer in said window.
  -  (3) If there is no window in the specified direction, then create one
  in that direction and display the target buffer in said window."
    (let* ((buffer
             (if (bufferp buffer-or-name)
               buffer-or-name
               (get-buffer buffer-or-name)))
           (window
             (cond
               ((get-buffer-window buffer (selected-frame)))
               ((window-in-direction direction))
               (t
                 (split-window (selected-window) size direction pixelwise)))))
      (window--display-buffer buffer window 'window alist)
      window))

(defun display-buffer-right--select-window (buffer alist)
  (select-window (display-buffer-fn buffer nil 'right)))

(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist '("^[*]warnings[*]$" . (display-buffer-right--select-window)))
```

__

**TEST**:  After evaluating the above code, test it by evaluating the following snippet:

```lisp
(display-warning :warning "hello-world")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```lisp
(add-hook 'special-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (let ((buffer-name-list (mapcar 'buffer-name (buffer-list))))
              (when (member "*Warnings*" buffer-name-list)
                (pop-to-buffer "*Warnings*")))))
```